# mysqli query returns the column name as one row in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

this is my login.php file

```
<?php require ("database_connect.php");?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>  
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])?>">
    Name : <input type="text" name="name"><br/>
    Password : <input type = "text" name="password"><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log In">   
    </form>

    <?php
    $name=$password="" ;
        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST" and isset($_POST["login"])){
            $name = testInput($_POST["name"]);
            $password = testInput($_POST["password"]);
        }//if ends here

        //testInput function
        function testInput($data){
            $data = trim($data);
            $data = stripslashes($data);
            $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        }//testInput ends here


        if(isset($_POST["login"]) && isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["password"]) && !empty($_POST["name"]) && !empty($_POST["password"])){

        //echo "Name ".$_POST["name"];

        if($result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='$name' and password='$password'")){            
            if($result->num_rows > 1){
            echo "you are logged in";
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                    echo "Name ".$row["name"]."-Password ".$row["password"];
                }//while loop ends here  
            }//if ends here


            /* free result set */
            $result->close();
        }       
        else{
            print "Wrong Credentials "."<br>";
            die(mysqli_error($conn));
        }
        }       
        //close connection
        $conn->close();
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

One problem is that my query 
        `if($result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='$name' and password='$password'"))`  returns column names as one row. I don not know whether it is ok ?  
 The other thing whether I put wrong name or password or correct , in both cases I do not get any output. What I am doing wrong here ?
 
 And if you can please tell me how to write a mysqli query in php with correct format with a comprehensive example . I searched on google but there are different ways so I am confused specially when column names and variables come in the query.

Comment: `if($result->num_rows > 1){` means that you're looking for 2 or more results from your query.

Comment: You have checked that the database isn't containing a row with the values of *name* and *password*?

Comment: @andrewsi as I stated in my question that my query returns column names as one row and I dont want to compare my values with column names. That's why I am checking for >1.

Comment: Dont use `mysqli_query` use prepare and execute. Or atleast use the escape.

Comment: @Adamnick - no. `num_rows` will tell you how many results are in your result set. The column names will not be counted in that total.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins yes , I have checked it , I have only one row in my table and only 2 column named as  "name" and "password"

Comment: @andrewsi it always return one row , whether values are correct or not and that one row is column names. This code `if($result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='$name' and password='$password'")){   
   print "rows are ".$result->num_rows."<br>";
   if($result->num_rows > 0){
   echo "you are logged in<br>";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
     echo "Name ".$row["name"]."-Password ".$row["password"];
    }
   } 

   $result->close();
  }` gives following answer . "rows are 1",
"you are logged in",
"Name -Password " ->this is column names.

Comment: @Adamnick - it's returning one row. So having your check look for `num_rows > 1` _will not work_. You're using `fetch_assoc` to load that single row into an associative array, for which the _keys_ are the column names, and the _values_ are the entries from the database.

Comment: I have updated my code , but still same (only column names in return) [link](http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/221D) , now I am checking `if($result && mysqli_affected_rows($conn) >= 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what do you mean but thats how i query mysqli

```
$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='$name' AND password='$password'");

if($query && mysqli_affected_rows($db) >= 1) { //If query was successfull and it has 1 or more than 1 result 
echo 'Query Success!';
//and this is how i fetch rows
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
   echo $rows['name'] . '<br />' ;
}

} else {
echo 'Query Failed!';
}
```

i think thats what you mean

**EDIT:**

```
<?php require ("database_connect.php");?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>  
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])?>">
    Name : <input type="text" name="name"><br/>
    Password : <input type = "text" name="password"><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log In">   
    </form>

    <?php
    $name = null ;
    $password= null ;
        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST" and isset($_POST["login"])){
            $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["name"]); //I updated that because your variables are not safe
            $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["password"]);
        }//if ends here

        //testInput function
        function testInput($data){
            $data = trim($data);
            $data = stripslashes($data);
            $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        }//testInput ends here


        if(isset($_POST["login"]) && isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["password"]) && !empty($_POST["name"]) && !empty($_POST["password"])){

        if($result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='{$name}' and password='{$password}'")){            

            print "rows are ".mysqli_num_rows($result)"<br>";//number of rows

            if($result && mysqli_affected_rows($conn) >= 1){//If query was successfull and it has 1 or more than 1 result
            echo "you are logged in<br>";
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    echo "Name ".$row["name"]."-Password ".$row["password"];
                }//while loop ends here  
            }//if ends here


            /* free result set */
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }       
        else{
            print "Wrong Credentials "."<br>";
            die(mysqli_error($conn));
        }
        }       
        //close connection
        mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have updated according to your [link](http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/221D) but I only get one rows and that row is column names . :/

Comment: i think that problem occurs because you're mixing procedural style with object oriented programming btw i updated your code see if that works (i edited my answer)

Answer (score 1):

Your test_input function is weak/unsafe, also, mysql_query is depricated, use mysqli and prepared statements as explained here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Furthermore, I included a section of code I use for my login system (bit more sophisticated using salts etc, you should be able to compile it in a piece of script suitable for you.

```
//get salt for username (also check if username exists)
        $stmtfc =  $mysqli->stmt_init();
        $prep_login_quer = "SELECT salt,hash,lastlogin FROM users WHERE name=? LIMIT 1";
        $stmtfc->prepare($prep_login_quer);
        $stmtfc->bind_param("s", $username);
        $stmtfc->execute() or die("prep_login_quer error: ".$mysqli->error);
        $stmtfc->store_result();
        if ($stmtfc->num_rows() == 1) {
            $stmtfc->bind_result($salt,$hash,$lastlogin);
            $stmtfc->fetch(); //get salt
            $stmtfc->free_result();
            $stmtfc->close();
```

Comment: I will surely test your code and let you know :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try to change this query

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='$name' and password='$password'")

to

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='$name' and password='$password' limit 1")
```

then you will get only one row , and try to change

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc()

to

$row = $result->mysqli_fetch_row()
```

then you can display the results by colomn number instead of colomn name

Comment: Don't forget to point out that the following if statement should be changed to `if($result->num_rows == 1){` - but that doesn't explain why OP is receiving the column names in the results.

Comment: I got this error `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::mysql_fetch_row() in C:\xampp\htdocs\facebook\login.php on line 34`

Comment: `mysql_fetch_row` is part of the `mysql_` library - it's nothing to do with `mysqli`

Comment: what I am supposed to do now ? @andrewsi

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
  mysql_connect("abc.com","user","password");
  mysql_select_db("database name"); 
  $query1="select * from table_name"; 
  $exe1= mysql_query($query1); 
  $row= mysql_fetch_assoc($exe1); 
  if($row["email"]==$_POST["email"] && $row["[password"]==$_POST["password"]) { 
    echo "Login successfully"; 
  } else {
    echo "error in login"; 
  } 
?>
```

enter your column name in `row["email"]` and `$row["password"]`

Comment: <?php
mysql_connect("abc.com","user","password");
mysql_select_db("database name");
$query1="select * from table_name";
$exe1= mysql_query($query1);
$row= mysql_fetch_assoc($exe1);
if($row["email"]==$_POST["email"] && $row["[password"]==$_POST["password"])
{
echo "Login successfully";
}
else
{
echo "error in login";
}
?>

Comment: Indent your code 4 spaces for it to show up in an answer. Or, paste your code, select it, and press the `{ }` button in the toolbox.